# Submodule of a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

Assume $A$ is a nontrival submodule of a free $R $-module, where $R $ is a ring.

Is it true that $A $ is also free?

Comment: The trivial module is free, as it is generated by the empty set. I think the result is false.

Comment: Think at $R$ as module over itself and a proper ideal $I\subset R$.

Comment: If $R$ is a PID, the answer is "yes", otherwise the answer is "no", not necessarily. If you had tried Google search on "submodules of a free module", you would have found this link: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16953/are-submodules-of-free-modules-free

Comment: As a simple counterexample along the lines of Cla's hint, take any finite ring $R$ which has a proper nonzero ideal $I$. The ideal $I$, regarded as an $R$-module, can't be isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $R$, since the cardinality of $I$ is strictly between $0$ and the cardinality of $R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All that can really be said in general is that if $R$ is an integral domain then submodules of free modules are torsion-free. On the other hand, every [projective module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_module) occurs as a submodule (even a direct summand) of a free module, so to find a counterexample it suffices to find any ring $R$ and any projective module over it which is not free. A nice example is a non-principal ideal $I$ of a [Dedekind domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain) with nontrivial class group.

A simpler example of a non-free submodule of a free module is the ideal $I = (x, y)$ of the polynomial ring $k[x, y]$, where $k$ is a field. $I$ cannot be generated by one element (exercise), and two or more elements must be linearly dependent (exercise), so $I$ cannot be free on any number of generators.